# Refresh database list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata

Is it possible to perform a database list refresh in T-SQL in the same way as in the SSMS right context menu Refresh option?

I've a 2014 Express instance with 197 databases inside. In my C# app I have a method used to get all databases names. Some times it only returns 34 results and in the next call 197.

I'm using the following script to get the database names :

```
SELECT name, create_date
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
AND name NOT LIKE 'ReportServer$%'
AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name, @create_date

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    EXEC(' USE [' + @db_name + '];
            INSERT INTO #temp_App
                SELECT ''' +  @db_name + ''',
                ''' + @create_date + '''
                FROM sys.extended_properties
                WHERE name = ''Application''
                AND value = ''app01''
            ')

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name, @create_date     
END 

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT * FROM #temp_App
DROP TABLE #temp_App
```

And the c# code to execute the script

```
List<DatabaseInfo> list = new List<DatabaseInfo>();
            
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        
                        command.CommandText = query;
                     
                        using (SqlDataReader resultReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (resultReader.Read())
                            {
                                string name = resultReader[0].ToString();
                                DateTime createDateTime = DateTime.Parse(resultReader[1].ToString());

                                list.Add(new DatabaseInfo(name, createDateTime));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception myException)
                {
                    log.Error("Error occured  " + myException.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the **Refresh** context menu item, for an object in the **Object Explorer** in **SSMS** is just meant to update the UI of **SSMS**.

It sounds like you're trying to get a constant list of database names. Without seeing your C# code, we can't tell you why you're getting a variable amount of names back.

You can use the [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) system view to get the most up to date list of databases (including their names). This will always be inclusive of all databases.

If you want only the online (and thus available) databases then a query like the following will get you that list (though that list *might* be more variable depending on how often you have databases going offline, or changing states, etc):

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'; -- can also use WHERE state = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for the T-SQL, but maybe if your goal is to use the keyboard to refresh the list you could use this:

1. Press F8 to make the Object Explorer active then press F5 (in this case it will work as Refresh, not as Execute query if you are in the Object Explorer).
2. You could create your own shortcut that is not assigned to any other operation
   go to the menu Tools > Options... navigate to Environment > Keyboard > Keyboard and search for View.Refresh or View.ObjectExplorer.

[image]